# Hindu scriptures discussing "proper education"

Tags: scripture, guru, gurukul

Are there any scriptures that discuss proper education or provide instructions or guidance to gurus/parents on providing proper education to children.

By "proper education" I mean education that helps a person develop good character, empathy, self-esteem etc. Basically a type of education similar to the one professed by Swami Vivekananda.

Comment: Generally parents as first guru helps a child in developing a good character, empathy etc. But Guru in gurukulas also were helping children studying at them in   developinig  such qualities by assigning different tasks to them. So what you are enquiring is already present in Gurukula  system of education .

Answer (score 1):

We have to remember that proper education, whichever branch the student may drift into, should have a strong moral foundation.  **brahmacharya - maintaining  celibacy** (one of the meanings) was made sine qua non, in this country,  for getting education.

A glorification of the Brahmachgri or religious student was mentioned in [Atharva Veda](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av11005.htm).

> 17. By Fervour and by self-restraint the King protects the realm he    rules. **By self-restraint the Master seeks a Brahmachari to instruct**.
> 18. By self-restraint a **maiden finds a youth to be her wedded lord**.

Importance of being self-restraint was stressed for both unmarried men and women in above hymn.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of "proper education" as vedic scriptures will be beyond what you listed in your questions as these things even abrahmic religion schools are teaching. The first aphorism of Vedanta Sutra states "athato brahma jijnsa" or now that you have taken birth as human enquire about God. Gurukul education uaed to train children to memorise scriptures after they have completed their understanding of sanskrit varna siksha. It is a deep subject and requires us parents to be educated first but very important aspect of whole survival of vedic dharma.

Comment: no references, needs a citation banner